# spring webflux (netty) handler can't parse ServerRequest containing json larger than 750 bytes

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

We recently started experimenting with spring boot 2.0.
Having the following handler code:

```
@Component
public class DataStreamHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> pipeEvent(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<String> reqBody = request.bodyToMono(String.class);
        String body = reqBody.block();
        System.out.println(body);
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromObject("OK"));
    }
}

@Configuration
public class RouterConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> monoRouterFunction(DataStreamHandler dataStreamHandler) {
        return route(POST("/pipeEvent"), dataStreamHandler::pipeEvent);
    }
}
```

It seems that the handler can't parse request containing json larger than 750 bytes.
when i searched how to configure max-http-post-size i found solutions only for tomcat,jetty and undertow.

How can i configure it for underlying netty?

Comment: Could you share a sample curl command? What happens when this error happens (what's the HTTP response? Do you see something in the logs?)

Comment: Would love to but when it happens i don't see any error and the client(postman) doesn't get any response. If I use smaller json then i get 200 ok and the json is printed to the log

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in reactor Betty - [look at this issue comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12164#issuecomment-367812420) for more on this.

You're not supposed to do blocking operations within a Handler.

You should change your code to this:

```
@Component
public class DataStreamHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> pipeEvent(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .then(ServerResponse.ok().body(fromObject("OK")));
    }
}
```

Comment: the block operation was just for the simple example, anyway the block is not the issue and doesn't have any affect.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code snippet I provided - what makes you think the block operator is not the issue?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer with a link to a known issue. I probably wasn’t able to reproduce this at first because I wasn’t using curl.